# Как правильно сравнить симовол в строке с верхнем регистром букв?

Tags: javascript

Как правильно сравнить символ в строке с верхнем регистром букв?

```
var str=new String();
str=prompt('Введите строку');
var n=str.length
for (var i=0; i<n; i++)
{
   if (str.charAt(i)==["A-Z"]) {
     document.write (str.charAt(i))
   }
 }
```

Я хочу, чтобы символы верхнего регистра выводились на страницу, не знаю как верно записать сравнение символа с верхнем регистром букв

Comment: строка содержит только латиницу (`A-Za-z`)?

Comment: Ошибка:
A - определение отсутствует

Answer (score 1):

Если я тебя правильно понял, то мне кажется как-то так (внутри твоего цикла):

```
var n=str.length, html = '';
for (var i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    var s = str.charAt(i), S=s.toUpperCase();
    if(S==s && S!= S.toLowerCase() ){html+=S;} // S!= S.toLowerCase() - отсекает всякие запятые и прочий хлам. ( Sergey Snegirev, благодарю за подсказку!)
  }
document.write (html);
```

Либо поиск в строке с использованием регулярных вырожений, но это я пока слабо представляю как...

Comment: Этот код выведет еще и запятую, например =)

Comment: if ( s == s.toUpperCase() && s.toUpperCase() != s.toLowerCase() ) { ...
вот так отсекаются знаки препинания и т.п.

Comment: хм, согласен. В данном случае тогда будет if(S==s && S!= S.toLowerCase() ){}

Comment: Подправил, благодарю за подсказку!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ".indexOf( str.charAt(i) ) > -1) { 
// do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно из исходной строки вытащить только заглавные буквы, то можно сделать так:

```
var str = prompt('Введите строку'),
    regexp = /[^A-Z]/g,
    result = str.replace(regexp, '');
alert(result);
```

В результате окажутся только латинские заглавные буквы.